# How to write a VB script that add reg and install cer - that i have in exe package

Tags: vbscript, registry, certificate, cer

I'm writing a vb script , that has gui , and also write to the registry , and install certificate that i have.

after writing the code i'm using iexpress , to create an exe file that will run all the files (cer and reg files) and install my script .

the problem is that i don't see the reg and certicate installing .

```
test=MsgBox("To configure wsus on you pc",4,"Wsus installation")
If test = yes Then

Set WshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
shell 'regedit -add "\\WSUS.reg"'
shell 'certmgr -add -c "\\wsus.cer" -s -r localMachine root'
shell 'certmgr -add -c "\\wsus.cer" -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher'

RestartServices "localhost", "wuauserv"
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox (Err.number & "-" & err.Description)
else
MsgBox "Certificate Install completed"
End If

Else

End If
```

Comment: have you defined yes as 6? [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/139z2azd(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: what ? i don't think so .

Comment: and the problem is that i don't see it working (reg and cer )

Answer (score 0):

The variable in `test` will not equal yes, but 6 or 7, 6 represent yes button, 7 represents no button.

So when you do the `if` statement, because `test` doesn't match yes as it is 6 it will not install and simply go to the `Else` statement which has no code in it before the `end if`

Comment: i wrote only this :     Set WshShell =              Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
shell 'regedit -add "\\WSUS.reg"'
shell 'certmgr -add -c "\\wsus.cer" -s -r localMachine root'
shell 'certmgr -add -c "\\wsus.cer" -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher'

RestartServices "localhost", "wuauserv"

Comment: you use WshShell, but only call using shell, also what is RestartServices. is it a code snippet not included?

Comment: it's restart specific services that i need .